# How to execute javascript from within an ajax request

Tags: 7, forms, ajax

OK, I'm doing some basic validation inside of an ajax form callback. I'd like to use the result to execute some javascript. What I've tried looks something like this:

inside my form alter:

```
if (isset($form_state['values']['field_temp_age'])) {
  if (validate())
  {
    //...return product information
  } else {
    drupal_add_js('alert("Validation fails!");', 'inline');
  }
}
```

This doesn't work. In this case, nothing is returned.

Also, tried this from inside the ajax callback:

```
function my_ajax_callback(&$form, &$form_state) {
  if (!validate()) drupal_add_js('alert("Foo!");', 'inline');
}
```

Not sure what's the approach here. How can I execute arbitrary javascript based on information returned from an ajax request?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using CTOOLS?  if not you should be.. there is a great validation library at your disposal.

Comment: Drupal. behaviors is the proper method for handling JS events as of D7.  A little bit of a learning curve.. but it is the proper way to have your code interact with the client layer effectively.   Not without mention it is extremely robust.

Comment: PhiloSurfer - I'm checking out ctools - thanks. What I'm trying to do is dynamically load product information based on a form field. I have this working but the ajax-returned data won't reload when the field is updated. I'm thinking ctools may offer some help getting the html in and out of the ajax wrapper, but I haven't found it... thanks for the tips!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure of how you are making the AJAX call, but jQuery AJAX calls such as $.ajax let you execute a callback after the result has been returned. I recommend returning FALSE or a code indicating an error to your calling function and placing your "validation failed" logic inside of that in the success handler.

Answer (score 1):

drupal_add_js doesn't work properly in an AJAX callback. If you need to execute a JavaScript function within an AJAX callback, here's the way :

First, in your form, you have to create the JavaScript function :

```
function my_module_form($form, &$form_state) {
// [...]
  drupal_add_js(
    'Drupal.ajax.prototype.commands.myFunction = function(ajax, response, status) {
      // Whatever you want to do. i.e. :
      window.open("http://www.google.com")
    }',
    'inline'
  );
// [...]
  return $form;
}
```

Then, in your AJAX callback, you need to call this function you created :

```
function my_module_my_ajax_callback($form, &$form_state) {
// [...]
  $commands[] = array("command" => 'myFunction',);
// [...]
  return array('#type' => 'ajax', '#commands' => $commands);
}
```

Hope it helps !